# Get PDF Page size from HDC C++

Tags: c++, graphics, hook, gdi+

I want to draw string in 3 location(Top, Center, bottom) of my printing page. I use `Gdiplus::RectF` and `drawstring()` to Draw string in the page. for setting string Location I need the Page dimentions. I have to Hook `EndPage` (Inject `DLL`) and I have only the `HDC`. how can I Get the dimentions of printing page?
here is my code :

```
int  StopPrint::hookFunction(HDC hdc)
{    
    sendinfo WaterMarkParams;
    rpcclient(WaterMarkParams);
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&m_gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    Graphics grpc(hdc);
    Gdiplus::FontFamily nameFontFamily(L"Arial");
    Gdiplus::Font         font(&nameFontFamily, WaterMarkParams.FontSize, 
    Gdiplus::FontStyleBold, Gdiplus::UnitPoint);
    Gdiplus::RectF        rectF(200.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush   solidBrush(Gdiplus::Color(100, 0, 0, 250)); 
    grpc.DrawString(WaterMarkParams.WaterMarkTxtstr, -1, &font, rectF, NULL, &solidBrush);
    return getOriginalFunction()(hdc);
}
```

Comment: I find [this](https://www.equestionanswers.com/vcpp/screen-dc-printer-dc.php) example that use `GetDeviceCaps` but it returns device information

Comment: I also find [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/764057/GDI-Drawing-and-Printing) example use device and monitor Dpi to draw with GDI on screen and to printer

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a printer driver that outputs PDF to a file.  When the DC is created for a printer, a DevMode structure selects many of the printing features, including the page size and resolution.  The page size and related values should be available using GetDevCaps with that DC.  Be aware that, with a printer DC, you'll generally get answers in actual pixels, and you have to use the LOGPIXELSX|Y values to determine the size in unites like inches.  If I recall, GDI+ assumes 96 px per inch and scales to the actual DPI.  So you'll likely have to do some coordinate conversions.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy thanks, this helps me and I found the dimensions close to the actual size by this formula `((GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZ|VERT RES)/GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELS X|Y))*96)`,  but i dont think dpi equal 96 for different monitors.

Comment: `HORZRES` and `VERTRES` give the printable area.  For a regular printer, that's usually a little smaller than the actual page size, because many printers can't print all the way up to the edges of the paper. I don't know whether the virtual PDF "printer" reserves a non-printable margin.  `PHYSICALWIDTH` and `PHYSICALHEIGHT` should give you the actual page size in device units.  If you divide those by `LOGPIXELSX` and `LOGPIXELSY` respectively, that should give you page size in inches.  See also the `PHYSICALOFFSETX` and `PHYSICALOFFSETY`.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy  Thanks for explanations. `PHYSICALOFFSET Y|X` return zero and `PHYSICAL WIDTH| HEIGHT` return as same as `HORZ|VERT RES` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find The method that is somehow close to the correct answer, it returns dimensions close to correct size, but it's not exact. I get the printable area of the page Width and Height in pixel by `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZ|VERT RES)` and get Number of pixels per logical inch along the screen Width and Height by `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELS X|Y)`.
Then I divide them and get page size in inch. After that I get pixel per inch by`(FLOAT)GetDpiForWindow(GetDesktopWindow())` and convert page size to pixel. It return dimensions but 20 - 30 pixel is smaller than correct page size. Anyway it work for A3-5 page size.
The code is:

```
   double WidthsPixels = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, HORZRES);
   double HeightsPixels = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, VERTRES);
   double WidthsPixelsPerInch = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSX);
   double HeightsPixelsPeInch = GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY);
   float  Screendpi = (FLOAT)GetDpiForWindow(GetDesktopWindow());
   rectF.Width = (WidthsPixels/ WidthsPixelsPerInch)*Screendpi ;
   rectF.Height = (HeightsPixels/ HeightsPixelsPeInch)*Screendpi ;
```

Comment: I hope someone know how to get exact size...